# How to Submit two values with only one submit button?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hey im making a website were you can send other users emails.

My problem is when I go and submit it doesn't submit both values?

my Form has a text box where the user wants to send the email and another is a text area which is the message.

and i don't want 2 submit buttons

Comment: Maybe some codez?

Comment: Are they in the same form? You will need only one form that contains both the input box and the text area.

Comment: u can send unlimited value with one submit button, will u show us the html/php code??

Comment: Why would two submit buttons help?

Comment: My bet is on some inputs being outside of the <form> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
/*... your code here
...*/
</head>
<body>
<form name='sampleForm' action='sample.htm' onsubmit='ValidatethisForm()' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type='text' name='formElem1'>
   <textarea name='formElem2'></textarea>
   <input type = 'submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

In the validate function once u finish your validations use "`return true`" to proceed. You can submit multiple form elements as long as they have different name attributes and the are within your form tag.

Comment: I'm utterly confused. When did validation *or* javascript come into play? How did this answer get here?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.1 on how to create forms.

Answer (score 4):

Your inputs need unique `name` attributes.

Example:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="recipient_address" />
<textarea name="message_body"></textarea>

<!-- no real need for a name on the submit button -->
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

any value that you want to send to the server make sure it is in the form tag. When the user clicks your "submit" button all of the data in the form is sent off along with the page request. You can have as many items as you want in the form.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best I have found is [here](http://www.whatstyle.net/articles/49/how_to_send_multiple_values_through_one_form_button)

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Check your `input` and add a unique `name` attribute.

Comment: Already mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6068753/2227743